# Is it ok to begin an essay/report with a quote?

Tags: essay, quotes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it ok to begin an essay/report with a quote?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4567/is-it-ok-to-begin-an-essay-report-with-a-quote)

I am writing an essay on project management within IT and in my introduction I will give a brief description of project management, to begin my essay I was looking at using one of these:

> 1) Project management is "A unique set of co-ordinated activities, with definite starting and finishing points, undertaken by an individual or organisation to meet specific objectives within a defined schedule of cost and performance parameters"
>
> 2) "Almost by definition, innovation relies on project management" (Wheatley 2004)

Would either (#1 vs #2) of these quotes be an appropriate way to start an essay?